# Sed match and replace only certain characters

Tags: sed, replacement

I have mutliple strings in very similar format.

```
(#1111111)
(#4444444)
```

I was trying to use sed to provide an output:

```
1111111
4444444
```

I have tried:

```
sed  's/(#[0-9]+)/^[0-9]+/g'
```

which seems to match ok, but the replace is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the format that you have in the question, there are two ways that this can be done:

```
sed 's/.*#\(.*\))/\1/' file
```

That will  print everything between `#` and whatever comes before it which, in this case, is `(`, and `)`.

This can also be done:

```
sed -e 's|^(#||g' -e 's|)$||g' file
```

That will remove `(#` from the beginning of the string and `)` from the end.

Output:

```
1111111
4444444
```

If it's a file, then you can add `-i` after sed to edit it in place. For stdout, pipe the command providing it into `sed`.

If this is a file or other output and there are differences, then you'll have to adjust the commands. I'm only operating on what you've provided in the question.